# Characterization of spherical harmonics.

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics

Let $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$ the circle of $\mathbb{C}$. We consider the applications  $h^{p}(z)$ defined on $C\ni z\to\mathbb{C}$ with $(p\in \mathbb{N})$  such that:

1. $h^{p}(rz)=r^ph^{p}(z),\quad r>0$ and $\int_{S}h^{p}(z)d\sigma(z)=0$ where $d\sigma(w)$ is the measure Lebesgue sur on $S$.
2. $\int_{S}|h^{p}(z)|^2d\sigma(z)=1$ and $\int_{S} h^{p}(z)\overline{h^{q}(z)}d\sigma(z)=\delta_{p,q}$.

They $h^{p}$ are called spherical harmonic.

Now we define  $P(z,w)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}!}h^{p}(z)\overline{h^{p}(w)}\exp(-\frac{|z|^2}{2})$ with $z,w \in C$, and the  transformation $$P(g)(z)=\int_{S^1}g(w)P(z,w)d\sigma(w)$$.

Put $\Gamma:=\{ g(w)=\sum_{p\geq0} a^ph^p(w) (w\in S):  ||g||^2=\int_{S} |g(w)|^2d\sigma(w)=\sum^{\infty}_{p\geq0}|a^p|^2<\infty    \}$ where $a_p\in \mathbb{C}$

For $g\in \Gamma$ i.e., $g(w)=\sum_{p\geq0} a^ph^p(w), w\in S$ a simple computation shows  : $||P(g)||^2_{L^2(\mathbb{C})}=\int_{\mathbb{C}}|P(g)(z)|^2dz=\frac{1}{2}||g||^2<\infty$ where $dz$ is the  measure de Lebesgue on $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that  $\Gamma$ is an isomorph to $(\Gamma, ||_S)$ onto  à $(A,L^2(\mathbb{C}))$ where $A:=P(\Gamma)$

Now, if we put $\Gamma_r=\{g\in \Gamma:   \int_{S^1}|g(w)|^rd\sigma(w) <\infty\},\quad r>2$ then $\Gamma_r\subset \Gamma$ .

**Is there  a characterization of $\Gamma_r$ ? as $\Gamma$  and can we find a function $\psi(z)$ such that** $$P(g)(z)=\int_{S^1}|P(z,w)|d\sigma(w)<\psi(z)$$

Any indications will be appreciated